# Benchmark & Test sites for latest browsers

Tags: html, browser, css, benchmarking

I am always interested in knowing what browsers support what and which are more up to date with CSS, HTML5 and other web technologies. The problem is that most of them only show very old versions like Firefox 4 when Firefox 9 is already out. Chrome 12 when 17 is already in dev channel and other similar examples.

Is there a site or sites that benchmark and test the latest versions of browsers and shows for example, how compatible they are with html5, webgl, css.. and what they support and still not support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for http://caniuse.com.

Comment: Wow!. Amazing site. I am going to wait a little more before accepting just in case somebody comes out with canireallyuse.com or areyousurethisworkshere.net or some other site.